# Model Predictive Control: Why the horizon size, $N$, must be equal or larger than 2?

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control, model-predictive-control

If you read "Nonlinear Model Predictive Control" by L. Grune and J. Pannek (and anywhere else), everyone says that the prediction horizon size $N$ must be larger or equal to $2$,$ N\geq2$.

Why?

Comment: That's simply not correct. You can use a prediction horizon of 1 if you want. Performance wise, it might be horrible, but that's another issue.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Maybe I misinterpreted what I read! But then, why do they, on that book, always state $N \geq 2$ if I could use $N=1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $N\geq 2$ condition in the referenced book is due to a slightly non-standard notation in the definition of the problem, using the objective $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \ell(x_k,u_k)$, which still makes sense for $N=1$ but typically would lead to the trivial solution $u = 0$ as only the current input and no future state is penalized in the objective. It would still be a well-defined problem, but perhaps a bit silly.

A more common form (in papers with a theoretical bias) is $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \ell(x_k,u_k) + \Psi(x_{N})$ for some terminal penalty $\Psi$, and then $N=1$ would make sense as the one-step ahead predictive control setup. Another form which would make $N=1$ reasonable is $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \ell(x_{k+1},u_k)$, as it typically makes no sense to add the current state to the objective.